# Initialization in Fortran Using Modules

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I use the Intel Visual Fortran. The problem I'm dealing with has many PARAMETERS and I want to avoid repetitious declaration and initiation of them at the beginning of each routine.

Is there any way for initialization these PARAMETERS using MODULES?
 
Of course the answer is YES, but some of intrinsic function are not accepted in the initiation statement.
 Here is a simple sample code,

```
    MODULE mod
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, PARAMETER :: x = SQRT ( 4 )
    END MODULE

    PROGRAM prog
        USE mod
        IMPLICIT NONE
        PRINT *, x
    END PROGRAM
```

Once compiled, the compiler shows me this **error :**

```
Error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   
[SQRT] Source1.f90
```

Albeit using **`ABS (  )`** is not followed by this error, but **`SIN (  )`** does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `sqrt` (and `sin`) intrinsic requires a floating point argument. There just happens to be both floating point and integer implementations of `abs`.

Replace `4` with `4.` and it should work.

Comment: God! What a stupid question! Sorry and Thanks you for your prompt reply.

Comment: I think you could blame on the Intel compiler error in this case. It just happened to be much more explicit in gfortran :).

Comment: In production code one should define a REAL with a KIND.